# Permission for user to be only in specific folder (debian)

Tags: ssh, ftp, debian, directory

I would like to have on my Debian server several users with SSH, FTP access. For these users I want setup permission 664. So far so good for me. But for this users should be great to not allow browse any other folders when there are connect through SSH. If user want to leave his home folder, system will deny it.

Could someone direct me to right way how to achieve that?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature of the OpenSSH server which allows for "jailing" users to their home directory (see http://www.howtoforge.com/restricting-users-to-sftp-plus-setting-up-chrooted-ssh-sftp-debian-squeeze), unfortunately this means that the users will NOT have access to their usual binaries. Unless you copy/hardlink a static version of the desired binaries inside their home folder, they will only be able to browse it using the internal SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them to use a [restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html). This will prevent them from using, among others, the `cd` builtin.

Use either `chsh` or `passwd -s` to set the shell of those users to `rbash`.